# how do embed ascx into dll (asp.net Server Control)

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-server-controls

i have an ascx userControl that want to call from my servercontrol
i call myUC.render(writer) to render output of my userControl. but dont render

how can i do this?

---

i load uc from dll with this help link
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/EmbeddedUserControl.aspx
this project help you to embed an ascx into server control and load it

but i have a problem with images and script  loading
images and script does not work

Comment: You are going to have to give way more information than that if you want your problem solved. And try to make your question clear - i had to read it three times to understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For user control to work, you have to host it into page or some other control. I will suggest that you load your user control in the server control (as early as possible in control life cycle - perhaps OnInit) and then in server control's render method, use the render call of user control as needed.

Comment: I find my answer!

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/EmbeddedUserControl.aspx

this project help you to embed an ascx into server control and load it